# ASP.NET Web API C# Linq select new, assign a default value to an element if it is null

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I've been struggling for a while now and I haven't found a solution on the Internet that works for my situation...

I have the following query in linq:

[image: Issue with code]

The last part I have underlined of "thisUserBestTime" I have situations were they might not be any record because the user hasn't played a level yet. In those situations I want a default value of -1 to be returned. How can I specify that in the code that I currently have?

Thanks in advance :D

---

Updates:

As suggested by David I've added the code as text below

```
var query = from lvlData in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevels
                    where (lvlData.IsPrivate == false && lvlData.DateDeleted == null)
                    select new {
                        Id = lvlData.Id,
                        FkUserCreatedBy = lvlData.FkUserCreatedBy,
                        DateCreated = lvlData.DateCreated,
                        LvlTitle = lvlData.LvlTitle,
                        LvlDesc = lvlData.LvlDesc,
                        isLikedByUser = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsLikes
                                            where (tbl.IsLike == true) && (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId) && (tbl.FkUser == thisUserID)
                                            select tbl).Count(),
                        numbLikes = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsLikes
                                        where (tbl.IsLike == true) && (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                        select tbl).Count(),
                        numbPlays = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsPlays
                                        where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                        select tbl).Count(),
                        numbCompleted = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsCompleteds
                                            where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                            select tbl).Count(),
                        bestTime = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttimes
                                    where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                    orderby tbl.BestTime
                                    select tbl.BestTime).First(),
                        bestTime_fkUserId = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttimes
                                                where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                                orderby tbl.BestTime, tbl.DateLastUpdated
                                                select tbl.FkUser).First(),
                        bestMoves = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBestmoves
                                        where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                        orderby tbl.BestMoves
                                        select tbl.BestMoves).First(),
                        bestMoves_fkUserId = (from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBestmoves
                                                where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId)
                                                orderby tbl.BestMoves, tbl.DateLastUpdated
                                                select tbl.FkUser).First(),
                        thisUserBestTime = ((from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttimes
                                            where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.FkUser == thisUserID)
                                            orderby tbl.BestTime
                                            select tbl.BestTime).FirstOrDefault())
                    };
```

The error I'm gettin is: "Nullable object must have a value."

My model for TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttime is the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The PK.
    /// </summary>
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// FK to relate to a custom level.
    /// </summary>
    public ulong FkLevelId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// FK to relate the ECS user.
    /// </summary>
    public ulong FkUser { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The date this record was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The last time the user managed to improve its previous record.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DateLastUpdated { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The best time (less time) achieved by the user for the level.
    /// </summary>
    public float? BestTime { get; set; } = -1.0f;

    public virtual TMagnecubeCustomlevel FkLevel { get; set; } = null!;
```

---

I've also tried to do the null coalescending operator and it marks it as an error saying: " Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'float'"

---

I've also tried as 'Sadly Full Stack' suggested to adjust the float type, here is the change I tried:

```
thisUserBestTime = (float?)(from tbl in _context.TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttimes
                                            where (lvlData.Id == tbl.FkLevelId && tbl.FkUser == thisUserID)
                                            orderby tbl.BestTime
                                            select tbl.BestTime).FirstOrDefault() ?? 1.0f
```

I still get the error "Nullable object must have a value."

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: @SadlyFullStack Already tried that, it doesn't work, it marks it as an error and I can't compile it

Comment: @SadlyFullStack it is "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'float'"

Comment: @SadlyFullStack I've tried that, I've edited the post (the las update). Still no luck. Did I do right what you suggested?

Comment: @SadlyFullStack Tried changind the model as you suggested, still getting the Nullable object must have a value

Comment: @AlexIbrahimOjea in your example, could you include sample data and write an example that runs on its own so we can test it?

Comment: @SadlyFullStack I've added the model of TMagnecubeCustomlevelsBesttime  which is used by thisUserBestTime. As you can see, BestTime is of type float? with a default value of -1.0f

Comment: with C# 10 , you can specify the default value inside the call itself like, `.FirstOrDefault(1.0f)`. try if this works for you.

Comment: The fact that you are getting a `Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'float'` error would imply that BestTime is float and not float? and that you need to change your last section to `select (float?) tbl.BestTime).FirstOrDefault() ?? 1.0f`